# Reactive cocoa attemptmap return type

Tags: swift, swift2, reactive-cocoa, reactive-cocoa-3, reactive-cocoa-4

I want to create extension on SignalProducerType as below.

```
extension SignalProducerType{
    func mapR() -> SignalProducer<[String:AnyObject], XError> {
            return attemptMap { (value: [String:AnyObject]) -> Result<[String:AnyObject], XError> in
                return Result(value: ["1":1])
            }
        }
}
```

XError is defined as ErrorType

```
public enum XError: ErrorType{
    case Invalid
    case Unsuccessful
}
```

But this won't compile and error is.

> 'attemptMap' produces 'SignalProducer', not the
>   expected contextual result type 'Result<[String : AnyObject], XError>'
>   (aka 'Result, XError>')

Comment: You don't return expected type from mapR method. If you return Result<[String:AnyObject], XError>, then it should be fine, as attemptMap returns that type.

Answer (score 0):

You are extending SignalProducerType who has generic associated types `Value` and `Error`, which means self is a generic type e.g. `SignalProducer<Value, Error>`. So you can't call attempMap with concrete value type [String:AnyObject] and concrete error type XError.

Replace the first line `extension SignalProducerType` with

```
extension SignalProducerType where Value == [String:AnyObject], Error == XError
```